# Spinner listener never triggered

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner, listener, android-spinner

I created a spinner into a Fragment, and associated to him a listener. The problem is that the `onItemSelected` is never called. I have put a Log message in it but I cannot see it. I put here the code:

```
    /**
 * Metodo chiamato appena dopo che è stato istanziato il layout. Ottengo gli oggetti in esso presenti.
 * Method called just after the layout has been instantiated. I get the object that are there.
 * @param view Tutte le view nel layout.
 *             All the views that are in the layout.
 * @param savedInstanceState Se si creasse un punto di ripristino dell'activity quando si chiude.
 *                           If there has been created a reset point of the activity when it's closed.
 */
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    spnLinee = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinnerLinee);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,elementiSpinner);
    spnLinee.setAdapter(adapter);

    DownloadLinee l = new DownloadLinee();
    l.execute();

    spnLinee.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Log.d("Linee", "onItemSelected qlks");
            lineaSelezionata = spnLinee.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, lineaSelezionata, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            Log.d("Linee", "onNothingSelected qlks");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: if there is only the one option (or even zero) is available for spinner the listener probably wont fire. what you gonna choose from?

Comment: I choose among data downloaded from a db. Now there is just one element.

Comment: But even if there are 2 element it does now works.